# How to hide category in joomla for certain users?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Description: I’ve two top level Categories SiteContent and UserArticles.
SiteContent contains all the site pages (Home, About, Contact) and UserArticles contains 5 categories (Music, Movies, Sports, Entertainment and Other). 
I’ve created a user with access level as *Manager*, who will be reponsible for posting content in the UserArticles categories. He has no rights to edit main SiteContent pages.
*What I want to do ?* Ans: When the *Manager* logs in using administrator panel, he should see only UserArticles category and the related articles. He should not be able to view SiteContent category and its respective articles. 
*What I’ve tried?* Ans: I’ve edit the SiteContent - Category Permission for *Manager* changed to Create - Not Allowed, Delete - Not Allowed, Edit - Not Allowed, Edit State - Not Allowed, Edit Own - Not Allowed. But the category SiteContent (Category and Articles) are shown for user *Manager*; its only disabled. *I want them to be completely removed* and show only UserArticles category and its respective articles. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with core Joomla but could make a layout override and include access checks for this. The theory of the Joomla administrator is that if you have access to the back and and to a particular manager that you can see it all but not do everything.